# Using CASE WHEN in a WHERE Statement to return ALL records if @parameter = 0

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, parameters, where-clause, case-when

I am using *Visual Studio 2008* and am *in a report* trying to create a query that has a `WHERE` statement that will return *all* records, if the `@parameter = 0`, otherwise I want the query to return only records that have the `@paramete`.

Here is the statement I envision, but can't seem to get correct:

```
WHERE (ADVISOR.staffPersonID = CASE WHEN @advisor = 0 THEN **'Do NOT
filter by staffpersonID'** ELSE @advisor END)
```

I have tried the following code which **doesn't** work:

```
CASE WHEN @advisor = 0 THEN ADVISOR.staffPersonID ELSE @advisor END
```

`ADVISOR.staffPersonID` is the field I would filter on, if the `@parameter` had a value other than `0`.  From what I've researched online, using the field itself as the `THEN` in the statement should work.  It does, unless the table (`advisor`) has no records that match in it at all.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
WHERE ADVISOR.staffPersonID = @advisor OR @advisor = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE 
 (@advisor <> 0 AND ADVISOR.staffPersonID = @advisor)
OR 
 (@advisor = 0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE ((ADVISOR.staffPersonID IS NULL AND @advisor = 0) 
    OR (ADVISOR.staffPersonID  = CASE WHEN @advisor = 0 THEN 
                                                ADVISOR.staffPersonID 
                                            ELSE  
                                                @advisor END 
                                ))
```